# Dynamically change a suppression list based on characteristics in a DE

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a suppression list that looks at data and adds or removes contacts to that suppression list based on whether a person meets that particular criteria at the time of send. Pardot does this through a dynamic list. Is there something similar for Marketing Cloud or does this have to be done through SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an Audience Exclusion Script. Essentially, there is the option in your interaction to add some ampscript logic that will exclude subscribers who are in the sendable DE that also meet the criteria outlined in the script.

Answer (score 0):

does the send happen at predictable time intervals?

If so, you could:

- Step 1: write a SQL [query activity](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm) (if you have the technical knowledge) or a DESelect "[selection](https://deselect.io/quick-tour?utm_source=sfse&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=sf-se-10)" (if you prefer a UI and don't mind introducing a third party tool)
- Step 2: create an [automation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_automation_studio.htm&type=5) and put the query / selection in it and schedule this so that the Data Extension is refreshed on an hourly/daily/... basis